# Access to iframe parent elements

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I try to apeend some link to some div content from iframe in my page to main window.

What I did:

```
var mainWindow = window.parent;
var link = document.createElement("a");
var node = document.createTextNode("http://localhost/" + 'dfgdgd');
link.setAttribute('href', 'dfdsfdsf');
link.appendChild(node);
success =  mainWindow.document.getElementById("suc_msg");
success.appendChild(link);
```

But it's doesn't work, I try to alert the `success` var and the result is:

> [Object HTMLDivElement]

But its not append the link to the html? why is that?

Comment: This code works for me... When you put console.log(link) at the end of the code, what does it output to the console? Did you skip some parts of the code - maybe you're mixing variables somewhere?

Comment: @PetrHejda its return the link, this is all my code